# expoappauth.getAuth:encountered exception when trying to start auth request null

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a react-natvie-app with google-service,
this is my code:

useAuth.js

```
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";

const AuthContext=createContext({});

 const config={
  androidClientId:"551241887947-trikk6eg7jvilk8cjrpp1maq10cb11gr.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  scopes:["profile","email"],
  permissions:["public_profile","email","gender","location"],
}

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

    const signInWithGoogle = async () =>{
         Google.logInAsync(config).then(async (logInResult) =>{
         if(logInResult.type === "success"){
           //login..
         }
       }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Api call error");
        alert(error.message);
     })
    }
  

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
          user:null,
          signInWithGoogle,
      }}
    >
        {children}
     </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function useAuth(){
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

here is my

LoginScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const {signInWithGoogle}=useAuth();
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>login to the app</Text>
      <Button title="login" onPress={signInWithGoogle}/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;
```

when I press the button I get this exception[image]

I am using a firestore.
in my firebase project I add the two fingerprint SHA-1
and SHA-256
I googled it and I didn’t  found any solution for this
problem.
thanks for the assitance!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this problem,In order to resolve you need to work with real android phone,and that's because the emulator is reason behind it.and it didn't work
properly.

Comment: Yep, had the same thing happen to me! Physical device works like a charm